# Table child inside another?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to know if there is any plugin that I can use to create a table inside another table, that is linked by an ID and I could expand, something like this:
 [image](http://icodeguru.com/database/Programming.Microsoft.Office.Access.2003/8368final/images/fig05_09_0.jpg)

Or is that possible to generate automatically, in a JavaScript function, for example?

Comment: Nesting of table is as simple as nested loops ,for tree structure  generating plugin, u can use http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples

Comment: Datatable can support nested tables, see: http://datatables.net/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jqGrid`. http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

There are so many designs available in jqgrid.

`Eg: jqGrid demos -> Grouping -> Multi Group all level sums`

Comment: jqgrid is great but quite heavy. I prefer datatable but as i said, jqgrid is great too.

Comment: I will use the table with hierarchy, i think it is the right one for me ;)

Comment: Please go head. I shared just one of the example in my post.